# Why does cycling use a measure of time ("century") as a measure of distance?

Tags: century

Wikipedia only attempts to explain the origin of the riding distance event but not why the term was used and why it "stuck".

Comment: It's also used for 100 runs in cricket, which is a noteworthy achievement, like 100 miles on a bike.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a misunderstanding about an English word and only tangentially about cycling

Comment: In the antipodes we might refer to a "tun" or a "tonne" as 100 km/h, or $100.   Neither is related to weight.  Example "I was draughting a truck and did the ton down the Raumati Straights" or "round the final cost up to the tonne and I'll call it even"   English makes no sense sometimes.

Comment: Used in Snooker, too (“century break” = at least 100 points in a single break).

Comment: For some people, it's both a distance and the time taken for it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A distance of 100 miles (161 km) is often referred to as a century. Century is also a common designation for 100 years, but that is not its exclusive meaning. The English word derives directly from Latin *centuria*, a group of 100 [[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=century)]. This is a form of *centum* (or CENTVM if you will) which simply means *(one)hundred*.

A ride of 100 miles is thus aptly named a century ride, without having to resort to metaphors or figurative meaning.

Chris H mentioned another instance where *century* is used to count something other than years: In the sport of cricket, a century is a score of 100 or more runs in a single innings by a batsman [[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_(cricket))].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50573/discussion-on-answer-by-gschenk-why-does-cycling-use-a-measure-of-time-century).

Answer (score 8):

If I read Google correctly, it isn't that a century necessarily means 100-years and a bike event borrowed from that. Instead, they are peers of one another.

The Latin root, centum or centuria simply means 100. In a more generic sense, it can simply refer to any collection of 100 [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/century).

Thus, a century in time is a collection of a common unit of time (year) and a century in biking is a collection commonly used units of distance (miles) or (km) for a metric century. The are both likely derived from the same Latin, not the later from the former.

Comment: To add to this, a *centi*meter is 1/100th of a meter.